# Finding $x=u+v$ from $R(A)$ and $N(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &-1 &0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &1 &-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Given any $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4 $, find $\boldsymbol{u}\in \boldsymbol{R}(A)$ and $\boldsymbol{v}\in \boldsymbol{N}(A) $so that $\boldsymbol{x}= \boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}$.

But isn't it not possible to find  $\boldsymbol{u}\in \boldsymbol{R}(A)$ and $\boldsymbol{v}\in \boldsymbol{N}(A)$ such that $\boldsymbol{x}= \boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}$ because $\boldsymbol{R}(A)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ which does not equal to $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: You should double check what $R(A)$ means in this context; perhaps it refers to the row-space.

Comment: So I found R(A)= span{(1 -1 0 0),(0 0 1 -1)} and N(A)={(1 1 0 0), (0 0 1 1)}. So does that mean for a u and v I could chose u=(1 -1 0 0)  and v=(1 1 0 0) or u= (0 0 1 -1) and v=(0 0 1 1) for my anwser?

Comment: No. The problem is asking you to figure out how to decompose an arbitrary vector into the sum of a vector in $R(A)$ and one in $N(A)$. Each of those will be a linear combination of the basis vectors that you’ve found.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to write that
$$
\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = 
\underbrace{\frac 12 (x_1 - x_2, x_2 - x_1,x_3 - x_4,x_4 - x_3)}_{\mathbf u} + 
\underbrace{\frac 12 (x_1 + x_2, x_1 + x_2, x_3 + x_4, x_3 + x_4)}_{\mathbf v}
$$

Comment: Where is the $1/2$ coming from?

Comment: We get a $1/2$ when we compute the orthogonal projection onto each space

Comment: Sorry, I'm either drawing a blank or haven't learned the orthogonal projection, could you explain.

Comment: Well, how about you set up a system of equations to answer the question instead?  Now that you understand what kind of answer you're looking for, maybe you can set that up properly.